# What would you call the distinction between e.g. 'cow'/'beef', 'pig'/'pork'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, food, animals

I'm looking for a term to denote the distinction between the name of an animal when it's alive, and the name of the same animal when it serves as food. If such a term exists, I imagine it belongs to psychology or anthropology?

Edit: we seem to have come to the conclusion that no such term exists, which is sometimes the correct answer to questions like this.

Comment: I believe the only word for that we have is the Norman Invasion.

Comment: And I am not sure how on Earth *psychology* is a suspect at all. Or is that a typo?

Comment: @RegDwigнt Perhaps psycholinguistics? Mental lexicon kind of stuff?

Comment: How would you use such a word? Please [edit] a sample sentence into your question.

Comment: A good question @RegDwigнt - I'm picturing something like 'we want to keep these ideas separate because we're squeamish about meat'. I don't believe that any such distinction exists for e.g. vegetables, because that doesn't involve a killing process.

Comment: @daisy Reg's first comment is actually a serious point: the Anglo-Saxon words (_pig_, _cow_) are used because it was the Saxons who looked after the animals, whereas the Norman invaders used the French terms (_boeuf_, _porc_) because they mainly encountered them on the dinner table. So it's a social categorisation, essentially.

Comment: Such a term exists only in sociology, as evidenced by Oliver Mason. Other than that historically important distinction, why would anyone care, please?

Comment: Related discussion in the answers of this post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280095/if-cow-beef-pig-pork-and-deer-venison-then-where-is-the-word-for-human/280096

Comment: @JLG: Also related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/553/animals-names-change-when-we-eat-them-is-that-universal

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Ah, the *psychology* connection is speculative based on needing a linguistic method to mentally compartmentalize the live animal from the slaughtered one. [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/e/animal-names-change-become-food/)

Comment: There is also the linguistic/psychological distinction between a thing and what it is composed of.  FWIW pig/pork (Gris/fläsk) and cow/beef (ko/nötkött) distinctions exists in Swedish.

Comment: @OliverMason - But the French have *vache* and *cochon* for the animals...

Comment: @AndyT But no Norman French speaker was actually dealing with _vaches_ and _cochons_, only the Anglo-Saxon servants. So these words were not used very frequently.

Comment: @OliverMason - Ah, so your comment is about why the etymologocial roots are different, and only tangentially related to the OP's question (why there exist two words at all)? Sorry, I though you were suggesting an outline answer, i.e. that the reason "pig" isn't used for both the animal and the meat is because of the Norman invasion.

Comment: @AndyT No: the word _pig_ is used for the animal, but _pork_ for the flesh because of the Norman invasion and the subsequent use of Norman French in the English ruling class.

Comment: Based on @OliverMason's comments I've re-read the question to check whether the comments are relevant. And I've realised that I have absolutely no idea what the OP is actually asking. What on earth is "a term to denote the distinction"? Can you give any examples of similar terms in other contexts?

Comment: @AndyT I understand the question as asking for whether there is a specific term for this phenomenon; I don't think there is. It's just language change caused by social change.

Answer (score 0):

In single words, the distinction has to be described as both "cultural" and "linguistic". Essentially, these words you compare are near "synonyms/synonymous", but each word's origin has been derived from a different language.  Since two commonly used words for the same thing then exist simultaneously, they often take on slightly different usages or meanings.  In your examples, the name of the animals (of French origin translation/transliteration - beef/boeuf, pork/porc etc.) are also associated with cooking (French common food usage **and** the names of the animals as well). The corresponding words "cow" and "pig" are of Anglo-Saxon origin, and are also commonly used for the animal name only.

https://www.thedailymeal.com/eat/why-pig-meat-called-pork

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/synonym